# Firefox NOT WORKING after Synaptic installed 67.0

Tags: 16.04, firefox

After notification, I installed Firefox 67.0 with Synaptic.
Firefox no longer loads anything!
Worse, using Chromium, I can't find Firefox 66.0.5, the last version that worked on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please have a look at the duplicate question, **there is a solution that does not require changing your profile**.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using the **refresh feature**.

**Please note that it will revert Firefox to its original state**: configurations and customizations, including extensions, extension data, and about:config preference configurations are removed.

Go the Troubleshooting Information page, that can be accessed by the following ways:

1. Menu: Help > Troubleshooting Information.
2. Type `about:support` in your address bar.

Click the <kbd>Refresh Firefox</kbd> button.

For more information, visit: 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings